# Applying align attribute to table header using Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know to apply css to DOM using jquery using .css() , I want to know is there any .attr or .att method so that I can assign align attribute to table header using jquery. If yes please show me the code.

```
<table>
<th >
</th>
<th >
</th>
<th >
</th>
</table>
```

Comment: there is no such th in my html. It is generated dynamically by ASP.Net engine. Actually its grid header. I am trying to apply the th{horiz-align:left } css in my css file but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code `$(element).attr("nameAttr",valueAttr);` like this you can add any attribute to any html element

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if that what you are looking for but you can add atribute to th like this

```
$("th").attr("align", "left");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough you should try `CSS` to set alignment but still jQuery does provide with `attr` function like:

```
$("th").attr("align","left");
```

Comment: Is it enough to set alignment on page load??

Comment: If grid is there on page load then it will be okay otherwise you will need to set it after grid is rendered. Also make the selector more specific so that it actually gets the `th` element in the grid header. If you are not able to fix it please post html of rendered grid header.